# Get and filter several columns with Spark and Java 8

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8

Well, I have a tsv file with 4 columns, id, user, data(string) and date. What I want to do is to get the user, data and date from the shortest data. So I try to that this.

```
        JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

         JavaRDD<String> lines = sparkContext
            .textFile(args[0]);

        JavaRDD<String> messages = lines
            .map(line -> line.split("\t+")[2]);
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = messages
            .mapToPair(string -> new Tuple2<>(string,string.length()));
        JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> reverse = ones
            .mapToPair(tuple -> new Tuple2<>(tuple._2, tuple._1));
        JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> sorted = reverse
            .sortByKey(true)
            .cache();

        List<Tuple2<Integer, String>> output = sorted
            .take(1);
```

With that, I have the shortest data and his length but now how I can relate this to the user and the date?? I don't know how to do it... any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store, whole record as your second field while creating the pair rdd using `Tuple2`. In Pair Rdd,make the key as your length of column `data` and value will be the entire record. Then after performing `sortByKey`, the pair rdd will get sorted based on the key(which is length of column data). And in the value the entire record is present,which you can access with `tuple._2` and then split with the delimiter and use whatever values you need from there.
something like below:

```
JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

 JavaRDD<String> lines = sparkContext
            .textFile(args[0]);

JavaPairRDD<Integer,String> pairedRdd = lines.mapToPair(lines -> new Tuple2((lines.split("\t+")[2]).length(), lines));

        JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> sortedRdd = pairedRdd.sortByKey(true);

        List<Tuple2<Integer, String>> output = sortedRdd.take(1);

        System.out.println(output.get(0)._1+" "+output.get(0)._2);
```

`output.get(0)._2` has entire record, split with `\t+`. And from the array, get the elements needed for you.